# Multiply sub-matrix by a constant

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have matrix

```
a =  [ 1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1;
       1 1 1 1]
```

And I would like to multiply the sub-matrix `a(2:3, 2:3)` by 5;
So that the new matrix is

```
a =  [ 1 1 1 1;
       1 5 5 1;
       1 5 5 1]
```

What function does that ? 
I've tried this = >

```
a = a(2:3, 2:3)*5;
```

But that would just give me a new matrix 2x2

```
a = [5 5;
     5 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the target correctly.

```
A=ones(6,6);
A(3:4,3:4) = A(3:4,3:4)*5

A =
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     5     5     1     1
 1     1     5     5     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1
```